# What is the usage of Nested comments in some programming languages?

Tags: programming-languages, comments

Why nested comments use by some programming languages such as MATLAB ,I just want to know usage of this kind comments in a program and what are the advantages we can gain  by using this nested comments ?

Comment: For one, you can easily comment out code blocks that already contain comment blocks.

Comment: @DrummerB : +1! Can you post this as an answer.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but I think that you're referring to block comments (e.g., `/* ... */` in C or `%{ ... %}` in Matlab) rather than single line comments (e.g., `// ...` in C or `% ...` in Matlab).

Comment: thanks @DrummerB
, horchler I was referring to  comment blocks inside another comment blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, coding standards for a particular project or program have rules about which comment style to use when; a common convention is to use block comments (/* */) for method and class documentation, and inline comments (//) for remarks inside method bodies and such, e.g.:

```
/**
 * Helper class to store Foo objects inside a bar.
 */
public class Foobar {
    /**
     * Stores a Foo in this Foobar's bar, unless the bar already contains
     * an equivalent Foo.
     * Returns the number of Foos added (always 0 or 1).
     */
    public int storeFoo(Foo foo) {
        // Don't add a foo we already have!
        if (this.bar.contains(foo)) {
            return 0;
        }
        // OK, we don't have this foo yet, so we'll add it.
        this.bar.append(foo);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

If someone wants to temporarily disable entire methods or classes in the above program.It's very helpful, if that language allows nested comments.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is nested comments allows  commented-out code that contains comments itself
example in C++ has block comments delimited by /*..*/ that can span multiple lines and line comments delimited by //.

Comment: just a suggestion: you could add a code example to illustrate your point

Answer (score 1):

You can use comments...:

- to temporally disable some lines of code.
- as titles for sections.
- to comment each line.
- to add some notations or comments on other comments.
- to send macro orders.

And you can mix all of them. That's why we need different ways to mark comments and create nested comments.

Answer (score 1):

Good old Turbo Pascal aka Borland Pascal allows multi-line comments either with curly braces `{ }` or with parenthesis star `(* *)`, which nest independently of one another even though multi-line comments in the same style do not nest.

A good workaround from my old work place was use of typical brace `{ }` comments for all informational comments and specialized use of the less common parenthesis star `(* *)` only to comment out code.  Marking the middle lines of commented out code with something like `**` is still a decent idea, and macros can be used to achieve this in programmer editors

```
function ComputeCost(var x : longint); 
{ Wide version: Apply discounts to raw price.} 

(* CODE GRAVEYARD!
** function ComputeCost(var x : integer);
** {Apply discounts to raw price.}
*)
```

Minimalists will always discount the need for nested comments by saying that C style languages allow constructs like `#ifdef SOMETHING` or the elegantly short `#if 0` to disable code.  True minimalists want old code removed completely and say version control takes the place of keeping old code.  A good counter is that commented out code together with programmer editors with folding support, e.g. Vim, allows visually stepping over dead code while keeping it for reference.

Answer (score -1):

I feel that nested comments are not necessary! In general a comment is omitted by the compiler so comments serve a main purpose for indicating the programmer what he had done or a new programmer to know the flow of the program..why unnecessarily nest comments..just an indication that can be without nesting.. eg:

```
    for(;;)
     {
        if()
          {
          }
     }/* a loop with an if condition*/ 
**need not be as**
/*a loop/*if condition*/for n times*/
```